# What is the meaning of invalid stream header: 4A000000

Tags: java, sockets, networking, inputstream

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 4A000000
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:866)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:358)
at NetworkListener.run(NetworkListener.java:106)
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: The error means that the header has an incorrect value. What kind of object are you trying to read, how did you write it out?

Comment: please show your code so we can help

Comment: It means the input data is not valid for ObjectInputStream. It was probably not created by ObjectOutputStream.